# Maze not working?

Tags: java, maze

code:
Array is a predefined boolean array that I made, and val is the length of the array (it is a square). I use it as a starting point, rather than using a random value

```
     import java.util.*;
     import javax.swing.*;
     public class Main
```

{

```
public void main()
{

String Val = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of rows/columns");
int x = Integer.parseInt(Val);

boolean mazeArch[][] = new boolean [x][x]; 
BoundariesDeclared(mazeArch, x);

generateMaze(mazeArch, x);
convertArray(mazeArch, x);
```

}

```
 public void printArray(String Array[][]) // Prints out the array
```

{

```
      for (int i =0; i < Array.length; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < Array.length; j++) {
        System.out.print(" " + Array[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println(""); 
}
```

}

```
   public void convertArray(boolean Array[][], int z)
```

{

```
  String RealArray[][] = new String [z][z];
for(int x = 0; x < Array.length; x++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < Array.length; y++)
    {
        if(Array[x][y] == true)
        {
            RealArray[x][y] = "*";
        }
        if(Array[x][y] == false)
        {
            RealArray[x][y] = " ";
        }
    }
}
printArray(RealArray);
```

}

```
 public void BoundariesDeclared(boolean Array[][], int y)
```

{

```
for(int x = 0; x < Array.length; x++)
    Array[0][x] = true;
for (int x = 0; x < Array.length; x++)
    Array[x][0] = true;    
for (int x = 0; x < Array.length; x++)
    Array[x][Array.length-1] = true;   
for (int x = 0; x < Array.length; x++)
    Array[Array.length-1][x] = true;
```

}

```
 public void generateMaze(boolean Array[][], int val)
```

{

```
Stack<Integer> StackX = new Stack<Integer>();
Stack<Integer> StackY = new Stack<Integer>();
int x = val / 2; // Start in the middle
int y = val / 2; // Start in the middle
StackX.push(x);
StackY.push(y);

while(!StackX.isEmpty())
{
    Array[x][y] = true; // is Visited
    x = StackX.peek();
    y = StackY.peek();

    if(Array[x][y+1] == false)
    {
        StackX.push(x);
        StackY.push(y+1);
        y = y + 1;
    }
    else if(Array[x][y-1] == false)
    {
        StackX.push(x);
        StackY.push(y-1);
        y = y - 1;
    } 
    else if(Array[x+1][y] == false)
    {
        StackX.push(x+1);
        StackY.push(y);
        x = x+1;
    } 
    else if(Array[x-1][y] == false)
    {
        StackX.push(x-1);
        StackY.push(y);
        x = x-1;
    } 
    else
    {
        StackX.pop();
        StackY.pop();
    }
}
```

}
}

Whenever I print the results, I only get stars, which mean that every single boolean is set to true. I understand my error, because I am visiting every spot the result will be that they are all set to true. But what can i do to fix this? I think I have the concept correct, just not the application. I previously asked the question and was told that I need to make two Arrays (1 for walls, another for visiting) but how would I apply this as well?

Comment: _"what can I do to fix this?"_ - How should we know? You make clear that it is not supposed to set everything to `true`, but you don't explain what it is supposed to do instead.

Comment: As I understood, after the neighboring cell is visited, the cell must be set as true in order to ensure that the cell is not visited again. This is why it should be set as true

Comment: can you also post how you call your method generateMaze, including boolean array and val initialization.

Comment: I just posted my entire code. I hope it helps in any way

Comment: do you aware that array index start at zero? For example, you have a 5x5 maze, you can access your maximum by Array[4][4], otherwise, it always results java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Yes I am aware of this. But it will not be an issue, because the borders are already pre-defined as true, so they will never be visited. This will prevent an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. This is done in the method BoundariesDeclared

Comment: Have you tried to step through your code with a debugger or intersperse detailed print statements into your code? Both of these debugging methods will give you vital details about the problem(s). Eclipse has a wonderful debug mode in it (press the bug instead of the arrow). If you aren't using Eclipse, you should.

Comment: I have not tried, but I will do so in the future

Comment: This code doesn't even compile!

Comment: `BoundariesDeclared` is where the issue is. Check your looping logic.

Comment: No it's not, the bug is in GenerateMaze

Comment: @AmirAfghani Sorry, it should work now. I left out some brackets

Comment: Hint: If you comment out GenerateMaze, the Boundaries are shown correctly.  But you have a closed Maze with no exit, and no obstacles!

Comment: @AmirAfghani I understand. This was the issue that I had a problem with

Comment: If you are trying to auto-generate a solvable maze, the complexity is totally on a different scale. Your algorithm now is fine for solving maze puzzle without dummy path.

Answer (score 1):

You **didn't mention what are you trying to do**. So not much we can help.

- What is this maze doing?
- What's your input?
- What's your expected result?

Add this line and debug yourself.

```
public void generateMaze(boolean Array[][], int val) {
        Stack<Integer> StackX = new Stack<Integer>();
        Stack<Integer> StackY = new Stack<Integer>();
        int x = val / 2; // Start in the middle
        int y = val / 2; // Start in the middle
        StackX.push(x);
        StackY.push(y);

        while (!StackX.isEmpty()) {
            Array[x][y] = true; // is Visited
            x = StackX.peek();
            y = StackY.peek();

            if (Array[x][y + 1] == false) {
                StackX.push(x);
                StackY.push(y + 1);
                y = y + 1;
            } else if (Array[x][y - 1] == false) {
                StackX.push(x);
                StackY.push(y - 1);
                y = y - 1;
            } else if (Array[x + 1][y] == false) {
                StackX.push(x + 1);
                StackY.push(y);
                x = x + 1;
            } else if (Array[x - 1][y] == false) {
                StackX.push(x - 1);
                StackY.push(y);
                x = x - 1;
            } else {
                StackX.pop();
                StackY.pop();
            }
            convertArray(Array, val); // add this line
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! This actually helped me see my error. I appreciate all the help

Answer (score 0):

The solution is still the same as when you last posted this question - you need to have two arrays

-one that is true for every place in the maze that is a wall - the maze's tiles

-one that starts all false - the solver's tiles

The solver can move onto a tile only if both arrays are false at that point, and sets the second array (the solver's tiles) to true while leaving the first array (the maze's tiles) alone.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a 'coding' bug, per say.  You simply don't know what behavior you want.  Try commenting out the line where you generate the maze.  Run your program with 6 as a parameter.  You get:

```
 * * * * * *
 *         *
 *         *
 *         *
 *         *
 * * * * * *
```

What kind of maze is this?  Where is the exit?  Again, this is not a coding issue, this is a design flaw.  Of course if you start within the bounds of this maze, you will visit all of the squares!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear what do you expect in your output exactly, but I can see where the issue is. In your `generateMaze()` method you are travelling like in spiral mode which ends up touching each and every node in the end. Like suppose you have 5x5 array, you travel and make true like (boundaries are already true) [2,2]->[2,3]->[3,3]->[3,2]->[3,1]->[2,1]->[1,1]->[1,2]->[1,3]

[image]

you start from middle, you start visiting and take turns just before you find already true (boundary or visited), and it covers all the nodes